# numpy ndarray hashability

Tags: python, numpy

I have some problems understanding how numpy objects hashability is managed.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> class Vector(np.ndarray):
...     pass
>>> nparray = np.array([0.])
>>> vector = Vector(shape=(1,), buffer=nparray)
>>> ndarray = np.ndarray(shape=(1,), buffer=nparray)
>>> nparray
array([ 0.])
>>> ndarray
array([ 0.])
>>> vector
Vector([ 0.])
>>> '__hash__' in dir(nparray)
True
>>> '__hash__' in dir(ndarray)
True
>>> '__hash__' in dir(vector)
True
>>> hash(nparray)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
>>> hash(ndarray)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
>>> hash(vector)
-9223372036586049780
>>> nparray.__hash__()
269709177
>>> ndarray.__hash__()
269702147
>>> vector.__hash__()
-9223372036586049780
>>> id(nparray)
4315346832
>>> id(ndarray)
4315234352
>>> id(vector)
4299616456
>>> nparray.__hash__() == id(nparray)
False
>>> ndarray.__hash__() == id(ndarray)
False
>>> vector.__hash__() == id(vector)
False
>>> hash(vector) == vector.__hash__()
True
```

How come

- numpy objects define a `__hash__` method but are however not hashable
- a class deriving `numpy.ndarray` defines `__hash__` and *is* hashable?

Am I missing something?

I'm using Python 2.7.1 and numpy 1.6.1

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: added objects `id`s

EDIT2:
And following deinonychusaur comment and trying to figure out if hashing is based on content, I played with `numpy.nparray.dtype` and have something I find quite strange:

```
>>> [Vector(shape=(1,), buffer=np.array([1], dtype=mytype), dtype=mytype) for mytype in ('float', 'int', 'float128')]
[Vector([ 1.]), Vector([1]), Vector([ 1.0], dtype=float128)]
>>> [id(Vector(shape=(1,), buffer=np.array([1], dtype=mytype), dtype=mytype)) for mytype in ('float', 'int', 'float128')]
[4317742576, 4317742576, 4317742576]
>>> [hash(Vector(shape=(1,), buffer=np.array([1], dtype=mytype), dtype=mytype)) for mytype in ('float', 'int', 'float128')]
[269858911, 269858911, 269858911]
```

I'm puzzled... is there some (type independant) caching mechanism in numpy?

Comment: This seems to show how you could get it to work, seems to deal with the fact that the array is mutable. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5173201/1099682

Comment: I understand that mutable objects should not be hashable. But here, my `Vector`class simply derives from `numpy.ndarray` which is not hashable, yet the `Vector` class is, even if it's mutable.

Comment: It seems to me that what is hashed is the memory ref or something, if you just repeat the vector = Vector(shape=(1,), buffer=nparray) and check its hash it should have changed.

Answer (score 8):

I get the same results in Python 2.6.6 and numpy 1.3.0.  According to [the Python glossary](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable), an object should be hashable if `__hash__` is defined (and is not `None`), and either `__eq__` or `__cmp__` is defined.  `ndarray.__eq__` and `ndarray.__hash__` are both defined and return something meaningful, so I don't see why `hash` should fail.  After a quick google, I found [this post on the python.scientific.devel mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/python.scientific.devel/2005-09/msg00035.html), which states that arrays have never been intended to be hashable - so why `ndarray.__hash__` is defined, I have no idea.  Note that `isinstance(nparray, collections.Hashable)` returns `True`.

EDIT: Note that `nparray.__hash__()` returns the same as `id(nparray)`, so this is just the default implementation.  Maybe it was difficult or impossible to remove the implementation of `__hash__` in earlier versions of python (the `__hash__ = None` technique was apparently introduced in 2.6), so they used some kind of C API magic to achieve this in a way that wouldn't propagate to subclasses, and wouldn't stop you from calling `ndarray.__hash__` explicitly?

Things are different in Python 3.2.2 and the current numpy 2.0.0 from the repo.  The `__cmp__` method no longer exists, so hashability now requires `__hash__` and `__eq__` (see [Python 3 glossary](http://docs.python.org/py3k/glossary.html#term-hashable)).  In this version of numpy, `ndarray.__hash__` is defined, but it is just `None`, so cannot be called.  `hash(nparray)` fails and`isinstance(nparray, collections.Hashable)` returns `False` as expected.  `hash(vector)` also fails.

Comment: THanks a lot for your answer. Regarding your edit, I do not reproduce what you say. I actually have  
    >>> nparray.__hash__()
    269709177
    >>> id(nparray)
    4315346832
so I'm still puzzled. I'm adding this in my post as code is unreadable in comments

Comment: Hmm... the hashes are the same the ids for me in Python 2.6.6 and numpy 1.3.0, but not in Python 2.7.2 and numpy 1.5.1.  This is all very strange.  It would probably help if I didn't happen to have a different version of numpy on every version of Python I have knocking around.  Anyway, as far as I can see, the default definition of `__hash__` has returned the `id`  for quite some time, so I suppose  they must have explicitly overridden it to do something different in at least some versions of numpy.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a clear answer, but here is some track to follow to understand this behavior.

I refer here to the numpy code of the 1.6.1 release.

According to `numpy.ndarray` object implementation (look at, `numpy/core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.c`), `hash` method is set to `NULL`.

```
NPY_NO_EXPORT PyTypeObject PyArray_Type = {
#if defined(NPY_PY3K)
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
#else
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
    0,                                          /* ob_size */
#endif
    "numpy.ndarray",                            /* tp_name */
    sizeof(PyArrayObject),                      /* tp_basicsize */
    &array_as_mapping,                          /* tp_as_mapping */
    (hashfunc)0,                                /* tp_hash */
```

This `tp_hash` property seems to be overridden in `numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c`. See `DUAL_INHERIT`, `DUAL_INHERIT2` and `initmultiarray` function where `tp_hash` attribute is modified.

Ex:
   PyArrayDescr_Type.tp_hash = PyArray_DescrHash

According to `hashdescr.c`, hash is implemented as follow:

```
* How does this work ? The hash is computed from a list which contains all the
* information specific to a type. The hard work is to build the list
* (_array_descr_walk). The list is built as follows:
*      * If the dtype is builtin (no fields, no subarray), then the list
*      contains 6 items which uniquely define one dtype (_array_descr_builtin)
*      * If the dtype is a compound array, one walk on each field. For each
*      field, we append title, names, offset to the final list used for
*      hashing, and then append the list recursively built for each
*      corresponding dtype (_array_descr_walk_fields)
*      * If the dtype is a subarray, one adds the shape tuple to the list, and
*      then append the list recursively built for each corresponding type
*      (_array_descr_walk_subarray)
```