# How to groupByKey a RDD, with DenseVector as key, in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have created an RDD with each member being a key value pair with the key being a `DenseVector` and value being an `int`. e.g.

```
[(DenseVector([3,4]),10),  (DenseVector([3,4]),20)]
```

Now I want to group by the key `k1`: `DenseVector([3,4])`. I expect the behaviour to be grouping all the values of the key `k1` which are `10` and `20`. But the result I get is

```
[(DenseVector([3,4]), 10), (DenseVector([3,4]), 20)]
```

instead of

```
[(DenseVector([3,4]), [10,20])]
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

The code for the same is :

```
#simplified version of code
#rdd1 is an rdd containing [(DenseVector([3,4]),10),  (DenseVector([3,4]),20)]
rdd1.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1])))
print(rdd1.collect())
```

Comment: what's the code you are doing? this seems odd that describing what you did you get that result!

Comment: I just added the code.

Comment: What you are doing is correct! I think that there might be an issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, thats a tricky question and short answer is you can't. To understand why you'll have to dig deeper into `DenseVector` implementation. `DenseVector` is simply a wrapper around NumPy `float64` `ndarray`

```
>>> dv1 = DenseVector([3.0, 4.0])
>>> type(dv1.array)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> dv1.array.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Since NumPy `ndarrays`, unlike `DenseVector` are mutable cannot be hashed in a meaningful way, although what is interesting provide `__hash__` method. There is an interesting question which covers this issue (see: [numpy ndarray hashability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785514/numpy-ndarray-hashability)).

```
>>> dv1.array.__hash__() is None
False
>>> hash(dv1.array)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

`DenseVector` inherits `__hash__` method from `object` and it is simply based on an `id` (memory address of a given instance):

```
>>> id(d1) / 16 == hash(d1)
True
```

Unfortunately it means that two `DenseVectors` with the same content have different hashes:

```
>>> dv2 = DenseVector([3.0, 4.0])
>>> hash(dv1) == hash(dv2)
False
```

What can you do? The simplest thing is to use an immutable data structure which provides consistent `hash` implementation, for example tuple:

```
rdd.groupBy(lambda (k, v): tuple(k))
```

**Note**: In practice using arrays as a key is most likely a bad idea. With large number of elements hashing process can be far to expensive to be useful. Still, if you really need something like this Scala seems to work just fine:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

val rdd = sc.parallelize(
    (Vectors.dense(3, 4), 10) :: (Vectors.dense(3, 4), 20) :: Nil)
rdd.groupByKey.collect
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer!

Comment: Thanks ! Precisely what I am missing !

Comment: Thanks. I've created an issue on JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9098

Comment: It works perfectly fine with Scala, that why I was surprised with the results.

Comment: What is interesting Scala is using breeze vectors which are mutable as well and it is possible to mutate a vector using output from `toArray`: `val y = Vectors.dense(1, 2, 3); val h1 = y.hashCode; y.toArray(0) = -1; h1 == y.hashCode`. Well, Python is much more opinionated when it comes to things like this I guess.