# Trying to put matrices into a set using python, but it still allows duplicates

Tags: python, matrix, set

I have a simple piece of code which doesn't run as expected.

```
from numpy import *
from numpy.linalg import *
from sets import Set

W = matrix('1, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, -1, -1; 1, -1, 2, -2; 1, -1, -2, 2')
E = matrix('1, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, -1, -1; 1, -1, 2, -2; 1, -1, -2, 2')

matrices = Set([])
matrices.add(W)
matrices.add(E)
matrices
```

The matrices are identical, however they both appear seperately when I print the contents of the set.  However, if I assign it like below, then the duplicate does not appear.

```
W = matrix('1, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, -1, -1; 1, -1, 2, -2; 1, -1, -2, 2')
E = W
```

Any idea what is happening?  I need a way of avoiding duplicate matrices in a program I am writing, which generates a tonne of matrices.

EDIT:  I want the following output

```
set([matrix([[ 1,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 1,  1, -1, -1],
        [ 1, -1,  2, -2],
        [ 1, -1, -2,  2]])])
```

but instead get the following:

```
set([matrix([[ 1,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 1,  1, -1, -1],
        [ 1, -1,  2, -2],
        [ 1, -1, -2,  2]]), matrix([[ 1,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 1,  1, -1, -1],
        [ 1, -1,  2, -2],
        [ 1, -1, -2,  2]])])
```

Comment: Don't import `sets`, use the built-in function `set()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a Python set([]) check if two objects are equal? What methods does an object need to define to customise this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942303/how-does-a-python-set-check-if-two-objects-are-equal-what-methods-does-an-o).

Comment: What is your desired output? Please give us an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of "Constructing a python set from a numpy matrix" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939228/constructing-a-python-set-from-a-numpy-matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into issues with how python implements checking for similarity between objects internally. Specifically, how objects considered "hashable" are compared.

The way that the python `set` constructor decides if two objects are the same is based on calling a magic method called `__hash__` (and another called `__eq__`). Two objects are considered the same if the result of calling `__hash__` on them returns the same value (and caling `__eq__` on them returns `True`). If calling `__hash__` on the two objects gives different values, `set` assumes they cannot be considered the same.

It is also worth noting that sets can *only* contain objects that are considered "hashable", that is, those objects which implement the `__hash__` method.

Lets see how this works:

```
In [73]: a = "one"
In [74]: b = "one"
In [75]: c = "two"

In [76]: a.__hash__()
Out[76]: -261223665

In [77]: b.__hash__()
Out[77]: -261223665

In [78]: c.__hash__()
Out[78]: 323309869

In [79]: set([a,b,c])
Out[79]: set(['two', 'one'])
```

Now, lets import numpy, and see what the hash values are for your matrices.

```
In [81]: import numpy as np
In [82]: W = np.matrix('1, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, -1, -1; 1, -1, 2, -2; 1, -1, -2, 2')
In [83]: E = np.matrix('1, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, -1, -1; 1, -1, 2, -2; 1, -1, -2, 2')

In [84]: W.__hash__()
Out[84]: 4879307

In [85]: E.__hash__()
Out[85]: 4879135
```

Notice that the hashes are different for `E` and `W` even though they seem to contain the same thing. Since their hashes are different, they're going to show up as different objects in the set. When you do assignment like `W = E`, then the names `W` and `E` are actually referring to the same object.

If you need a workaround for this, you could store the strings you're using to build the matrices:

```
In [86]: set(['1, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, -1, -1; 1, -1, 2, -2; 1, -1, -2, 2',
              '1, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, -1, -1; 1, -1, 2, -2; 1, -1, -2, 2'])
Out[86]: set(['1, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, -1, -1; 1, -1, 2, -2; 1, -1, -2, 2'])
```

Comment: Not quite 100% accurate. Sets use `__eq__`, but assume `__hash__` is usable as a fast approximation; if the hashes are different, the objects cannot be equal, but if the hashes match, then the objects only *might* be equal. Full equality must then be checked.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I left it out originally because it isn't directly related to the problem, but I've added a couple parentheticals to my answer for completeness's sake.

Comment: Thanks, still new to python.  I ended up storing the string representations of the matrices into sets and it works.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because sets use **__*eq*__** and **__*hash*__** special methods to detect equality of items (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). But matrix objects have different hashes and those **__*eq*__** method doesn't return true/false, but matrix instead:

```
>>> W == E
matrix([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> W > E
matrix([[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 2):

`matrix` doesn't have very well behaved `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods when it comes to using them in `set`. If you want to use a `set` to make them unique, you need to wrap the matrix in a helper class. Something simple like this should do;

```
import hashlib

class MatrixWrap:
     def __init__(self, matrix):
         self.matrix = matrix
     def __hash__(self):
         return int(hashlib.sha1(self.matrix).hexdigest(), 16)
     def __eq__(self, x):
         return self.__hash__() == x.__hash__()
```

Then you can just do;

```
from numpy import *
from numpy.linalg import *

W = matrix('1, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, -1, -1; 1, -1, 2, -2; 1, -1, -2, 2')
E = matrix('1, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, -1, -1; 1, -1, 2, -2; 1, -1, -2, 2')
X = matrix('2, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, -1, -1; 1, -1, 2, -2; 1, -1, -2, 2')

matrices = set()
matrices.add(MatrixWrap(W))
matrices.add(MatrixWrap(E))
matrices.add(MatrixWrap(X))

for a in matrices:
    print a.matrix
```

...to get your unique matrices listed.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers and comments have been good and identified the problem and @Joachim Isaksson 's identified a good solution. I wanted to point out that you can also serialize a regular array and dump/load the data into the set like this:

```
import numpy as np

def arrayToTuple(arr):
    arrType = arr.dtype.str
    arrShape = arr.shape
    arrData = arr.tostring()

    return (arrType,arrShape,arrData)

def tupleToArray(tupl):
    arrType, arrShape, arrData = tupl

    return np.matrix( np.fromstring(arrData, dtype=arrType).reshape(arrShape) )
        # remove the matrix( ) wrap to return arrays instead of matrices
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
W = matrix('1, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, -1, -1; 1, -1, 2, -2; 1, -1, -2, 2')
E = matrix('1, 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, -1, -1; 1, -1, 2, -2; 1, -1, -2, 2')

matrixTuples = set()

matrixTuples.add(arrayToTuple(W))
matrixTuples.add(arrayToTuple(E))

for mTupl in matrixTuples:
    print tupleToArray(mTupl)
```

This will also work with regular bool, integer and float arrays (but not object or string arrays) -- just remove the matrix( ) wrapper on the arrayFromTuple return.  I guess those functions may be better named matrixToTuple and tupleToMatrix but they are very close regardless of whether you are working with matrices or arrays.