# TypeError: unhashable type: 'matrix'

Tags: python, numpy

I struggle with a error like below.
I saw this code from another book, but it doesn't work.
How can I solve it?
Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
a = [1, 2, 3, 2]
Ma = np.mat(a)
Sa2 = set(Ma)      #error
```

Comment: What do you expect to be in the set? Can't you just do `Sa2 = set(a)`?

Comment: Above code is briefly summarized, in real code, it is hard to refer to a.

Comment: Use the underlying array data : `set(Ma.A1)`?

Comment: Anyway it works, but if a is multi-dimension list and dynamically refered, then how to use it?. It means not A1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following in order to flatten the matrix to an ndarray.

```
import numpy as np
a = [1, 2, 3, 2]
Ma = np.mat(a)
Sa2 = set(np.asarray(Ma).ravel())
print (Sa2)
>>> '{1, 2, 3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ma.A1` to convert the matrix to a 1d array, which displays as a simple list. Wrap that in tuple makes an object that is **hashable**.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 2]
>>> Ma = np.mat(a)
>>> Sa2 = set(Ma)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'matrix'
>>> set(Ma.A1)
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Another way:

```
>>> set(Ma.flat)
set([1, 2, 3])
```

See more details from [Set of matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897737/set-of-matrices)

and [Constructing a python set from a numpy matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939228/constructing-a-python-set-from-a-numpy-matrix).

Answer (score 0):

`set` tries to iterate on its input, in effect treating it as a list:

```
In [61]: list(np.mat([1,2,3,4]))
Out[61]: [matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4]])]     # a 1 item list
In [62]: list(np.mat([1,2,3,4]).A1)
Out[62]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`np.mat` turns its input into a (1,4) array, and any iteration on that produces the same thing.  And `set` can't hash the whole matrix object.

What do you want a `set` of, the 4 numbers in the matrix? Or a 'row' of the matrix?  `set` does not work with nested lists or lists containing arrays or matrices.  The elements of the set have to be 'hashable', immutable.  Numbers and tuples work.  Lists and dictionaries don't.